# Should I add keystore files to version control?

Tags: security, version-control, ssh-keys

Is there any reason to not store keystore files in version control?  Is there a security risk to doing so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should **not** store keystore files in your version control repository, as there is a huge security risk in doing so.  The issue isn't how *much* of a risk it is, but rather, the fact that it's just an *unnecessary* risk, especially when best practices dictate you *should not* include security credentials in your source code/repository (keep your code & application logic separate from data).

Now in terms of severity, this is a **huge** security risk, best practices aside.  Several third-party tools have already been developed to extract private keys out of an existing keystore (two notable examples being [jksExportKey](http://miteff.com/jksexportkey) and [KeyStore Explorer](http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net/), although note that several other tools also exist).

Comment: How about an encrypted keystore file, using something like `openssl enc -aes-256-cbc` ?

Comment: @Styler I would then question why exactly you would want to keep AES-encrypted data under version control (not to mention the random nature of the data would be highly inefficient for most VCS programs, and any differences between commits would just look like a large amount of random data).

Comment: I dont want to, but the CI tool doesnt allow files to be stored locally, and I need to give the build tool on that box a keystore.

Comment: @Styler admittedly, this is now getting out of my depth/field.  If you're just doing this for **development** and not production, using a test keystore, or providing maybe a *default* with the code, then perhaps you can justify including it.  I just feel it's important to stress that including credentials in version control is bad practice, both due to the security risks, and inefficiencies of version control dealing with binary data.